# Aspose.Words - Find and replace functionality - find text with new line characters

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to search and replace the below text in a word document using Aspose.Words (Version 22.4). But, the Aspose replace function is not able to find and replace the text in the document.

[SERVICE WAITING PERIOD:

[[30 days] of Active continuous service.]]

I am using the below code, where

```cs
rule.MergeField = "[SERVICE WAITING PERIOD:\r\n[[30 days] of Active continuous service.]]";
```

```cs
mergedDocument.Range.Replace(rule.MergeField.Replace("\n", "&l").Replace("\r", "&p"),
"abc", new Aspose.Words.Replacing.FindReplaceOptions()
{ MatchCase = false, FindWholeWordsOnly = false });
```

I have also tried replacing the `\n`, `\r` in text with the Aspose Control Characters without any luck.
Has anyone tried something like this or does aspose support such search text?

Thank you for your help.

---

**06/09 Updates**

Replacing `\r\n` with &p as suggested by Alexey worked. thank you so much. Need help on the metacharacters for aspose for below text.

**\r**

**Example text** - Age at Date of Loss\rPercent of Original Benefit Amount\r[Age 70-74]\r[65%]\r[Age 75-79]\r[45%]\r[Age 80-84]\r[30%]\r[Age 85 or over]\r[15%]\r

**Word equivalent** -

[image]

**\t (Tab)**

**Example text** - COVERED LOSS OF USE OF\tPERCENTAGE OF COVERAGE AMOUNT\r\n\tFour Limbs\t[100%]\r\n\tThree Limbs\t[75%]\r\n\tTwo Limbs\t[66.67%]\r\n\tOne Limb\t[50%]\r\n

**Word equivalent -**
[image]

**UPDATES 06/15**

I tried to search and replace the text with \t but it does not work with below code.

```
 rule.MergeField = "Class II:\t\tWhile participating in game, please make sure to wear your helmets.";

 mergedDocument.Range.Replace(rule.MergeField.Replace("\r\n", "&p").Replace("\t", ControlChar.Tab),
 finalValue.Replace("\r\n", "&p").Replace("\t", "&l"), new Aspose.Words.Replacing.FindReplaceOptions()
{ MatchCase = false, FindWholeWordsOnly = false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace a sequence `\r\n` with `&p` metacharacter to match paragraph break in the `Document`. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");

string match = "[SERVICE WAITING PERIOD:\r\n[[30 days] of Active continuous service.]]";

// Replace \r\n sequence (which usualy represents paragraph break in text documents) with &p metacharacter
// to match paragraph break in MS Word document.
match = match.Replace("\r\n", "&p");

doc.Range.Replace(match, "abc", new FindReplaceOptions() { MatchCase = false, FindWholeWordsOnly = false });

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

`&l` metacharacter represent a soft line break, which is `\v`, you can insert such break in MS Word using `Shift+Enter`

UPDATE:

You can use `\t` character in your match string and replacement.

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
// Insert some content with tab character.
builder.Write("This\tis\ttext\twith\ttab\tcharacters.");
// Save an intermadiate result.
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\interm.docx");

// Now replace all tabs with sequence of whitespaces.
doc.Range.Replace("\t", "    ");
// Save the result.
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

The other character you have highlighted is cell break. You cannot replace it. Table cell in MS Word always contain a paragraph and the highlighted character is the end of the last paragraph in the cell. It cannot be removed.

Comment: Thank you, Alexey. That worked! Appreciate your help. Can you please help me with the equivalent metacharacters in aspose for the below text search?                                                                     \r and \t (tab)                                                                                                                              I have updated my question to include example of that text. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. I will try out the \t and will let you know.

Comment: Hi, Alexey, Sorry for late response.  I tried for searching \t, but it is not being searched and replaced via Aspose words. Please see my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a simple code example that demonstrates that tab characters are handles properly by find/replace mechanism.

Comment: That seem to work. However, when I use it like this doc.Range.Replace("\t", "\t"), I see a lot of 'extra space' between the words separated by tab. Also, can I replace "\r" with "\r"?  What we are doing is finding complex chunk of text with these chars enclosed in square brackets [this\r\tis\r\ntext] and either inserting this bracket or removing it from document based on action taken by user. Hence, I need to be able to find it and then keep it (removing the []brackets) or delete it from doc. I am not able to figure out how I can find such complex text shared in the screen shots earlier.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you share your input and expected output documents. You can post your request in Aspose.Words support forum and share your document there: https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8

Comment: Hi, I had posted there last week, but there is no response so far. Sorry, I am very new to Aspose and still understanding things. Will it be possible to share your email address or Skype Id? thank you.

Comment: Could you please share the link where you have posted your question?

Comment: https://forum.aspose.com/t/need-help-aspose-find-and-replace-functionality-find-text-with-new-line-characters/247378

Comment: For some reason the topic was uncategorized and was invisible for Aspose staff. I have moved the topic into Aspose.Words category: https://forum.aspose.com/t/need-help-aspose-find-and-replace-functionality-find-text-with-new-line-characters/247810

Comment: Hi Alexey, I created another post for some other issue with find and replace.. Can you please check if that is tagged correctly as well? Thank you. https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-word-find-and-replace-not-working-as-expected/248765

Comment: You posted your question a a private message. It is better to post questions in the public forum.